# Combining Graphic Objects Jswing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created a new class extending JPanel which contains this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawArc(x,y, width,height,start-angle, end-angle);
        g.drawLine(x1Pos, y1Pos,x2Pos, y2Pos);
        g.drawLine(x1Pos, y1Pos,x2Pos,y2Pos);
    }
```

Now what I want is to combine these lines,arcs and animate them together instead of writing a code for each. Something like creating a module of these and using them together. Is this possible?
Essentially, combining all these lines so that when I write code to move, I don't have to specify code for each, rather they move together.

Comment: Sorry can't understand what you like to achieve..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can with BufferedImages. Create a BufferedImage and paint onto the image itself.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage. TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) img.createGraphics();
g2d.fillRect(0,0,60,60); //do stuff with g2d here
```

Then, use the JPanel to draw each BufferedImage onto the screen

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    g.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g.drawImage(img,x,y);
}
```

Comment: `g.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());` is not required and is unadvisable, a better solution would be to just call `paintComponent` and let to do it's job

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

1. Don't use hard-coded "magic" numbers. e.g., not `g.drawLine(100-20, 50, 230-20, 50);`
2. Use variables instead. e.g., `g.drawLine(leftWall-xPos, yPos, rightWall - xPos, yPos);`
3. You will need an animation loop to drive your animation.
4. A [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would be a great way to do this.
5. Inside of the Timer's ActionListener, change the state of fields of the class and call repaint.
6. Have your paintComponent method use those fields instead of the hard-coded numbers, to decide where to draw what.
7. Use a BufferedImage to draw "static" unchanging background images.
8. Learn and use Java naming conventions. Variables should all start with a lower case letter.